# change serializer to show both id and title of a foreignKey field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using DRF and I have a Profile serializer with a group field that is a foreignKey to Group model.
Profile Serializer:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('group', ...)
```

Profile Model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # other fields
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Group Model:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Group Serializer:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('title', 'id')
        extra_kwargs = {'id': {'read_only': True}}
```

I have a route in my SPA that showing a list of profiles. I want to show the group title for each profile but this serializer only provide me an id of group and I don't want to create another view to get id of group and give me title. so I search about it and it was 2 solution first `StringRelatedField`that is `read_only` and `SlugRelatedField`. I changed `ProfileSerializer` and add `SlugRelatedField` like this:

```
class ProfileForAdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=False,
        queryset=Group.objects.all(),
        slug_field='title'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('group', ...)
```

now I have access to title of profile group but the problem is I have to create Profile with providing title of group field, but I want to create Profile like before with sending id of group and also have access to title of group without send another request. (sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered `source` argument on serializer field ?

It should be something like this

```
group_title = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='group.title')

class Meta:
    ...
    fields = ('group_title', ...)
```

[check here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source)